# Why won't an image show using FXML for JavaFX using Scenebuilder and Eclipse?

Tags: image, javafx, fxml

I've built a simple GUI using Scenebuilder with several buttons. In SceneBuilder, everything shows up fine.

But when I run the program, in all the buttons except for one, all of their ImageViewers' images display properly. I encountered this issue before, and after cleaning the project, things showed up, but not this time. I use document references to point to the images, and all the images used are present, which is that they are all in the same directory with the fxml and controller class.

Any idea what could be the cause behind the issue?

Edit:
Here's the (shortened) fxml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<fx:root onMouseDragged="#onMouseDrag" onMouseEntered="#onMouseEnter" onMouseExited="#onMouseExit" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="600.0" type="VBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <ToolBar onMouseDragged="#onMouseDrag" onMouseEntered="#onMouseEnter" onMouseExited="#onMouseExit" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="376.0">
        <items>
            <Button fx:id="closeButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#closeWindow">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="40.0" fitWidth="40.0" pickOnBounds="true" smooth="false">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@images/close-32.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
        </items>
      </ToolBar>
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

Here's the simple controller. I explicitly call setup on the the hosting Stage

```
public LogViewerControllerFX() {
    Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
}

public void setup() {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
            "LogViewerFX.fxml"));

    fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);

    try {
        fxmlLoader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here's the Stage:

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class LogViewerDialogFX extends Stage {

    public LogViewerDialogFX() {
        LogViewerControllerFX logViewController = new LogViewerControllerFX();
        logViewController.setup();  

        Scene scene = new Scene(logViewController);
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        setScene(scene);
        initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        setTitle(I18N.getText("title.logViewer"));
        getIcons().add(new Image("net/logviewer/image/logs-25.png"));
    }
}
```

This all happens within the JavaFX thread, of course.

Comment: It's almost impossible to tell, by what I can read in your description. My guess would be a misspelled name. Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: I've been trying, but it works everywhere else. I wish it were misspelled but I went over the fxml, scenebuilder, and the images themselves, and they all check out. It's also a bit annoying that I have to clean and build the project in Eclipse each time I make changes in Scenebuilder, else the changes won't reflect during runtime. Perhaps that's the root of the issue?

Comment: post the code of the FXML and the code you have for the non working button.

Comment: code added. I'm using the latest e(FX)clipse plugin for Scenebuilder btw.

Comment: Since you said the images are in the same folder as the fxml, instead of using `<Image url="@images/close-32.png" />` try `<Image url="@close-32.png" />`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try an rebuild of your eclipse project.
Or try to set the Image over css.

`<Button styleClass="Button-Image"/>`

```
.Button-Image{
    -fx-graphic: url('images/close-32.png');
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested your answer but I don't want to accept my answer as it isn't a very good one, and you're the only one who put up a working answer to credit, so the credit is yours.

Comment: Yes instead of -fx-image you must use -fx-graphic. Edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong but please take a look here:

```
<Image url="@images/close-32.png" />
```

Refers to an image in '/images/' folder. However:

```
getIcons().add(new Image("net/logviewer/image/logs-25.png"));
```

Refers to an image in '/image/' folder.
As you can see, they both refers to different folder. You may want to check which one is the right one, 'image/' or 'images/' folder.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. it's just a typo when I edited the posted code down to what it is. On my actual code, it was correct. Anyway, the new [SceneBuilder I use from gluOn](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/) never gave me this problem since I started using it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what constitutes a good answer or not, but I got it working by redoing the references to all images involved (they turned out the same on the fxml, however), rebooted Eclipse and SceneBuilder, and perfomed a complete clean of all projects.

Like I noticed before, only after cleaning do changes in SceneBuilder become usable in Eclipse. I'm not sure if it's the e(fx)clipse plugin, or how Eclipse treats fxml files, but there's definitely something in need of improvement in that particular process.

Comment: if an external process modifies file Eclipse is not detecting that by default but you need to hit refresh - you can only look in Preferences > Workspace and check the "Refresh using native hooks or polling"

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I hope it works. I found another (horrible) workaround, which was to copy the images straight into the build folder where they should reside. If nothing works for you, at least there's a last resort.